# Здравствуйте друзья, только учу JavaScript, мне немного непонятны некоторые моменты, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

```
function getFizzBuzz(num) {
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
         (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) ? console.log("fizzbuzz") : (i % 5 == 0) ? console.log("buzz") : (i % 3 == 0) ? console.log("fizz") : console.log(i);
       }   
       return;
   }
let num = +prompt("Please, write some number: ", 0);
getFizzBuzz(num);
```

1. Когда я пишу "return" после цикла, тогда выводит все последовательно, именно столько значений в столбик сколько я ввёл в prompt, а если в цикле самом пишу return, то выводит только одно первое значение "fizzbuzz".
2. Если я напишу (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) в конце условия, после i % 3 == 0 и % 5 == 0, то оно не выполняется, почему так происходит ? Выводятся только числа делимые на 3 и на 5 по отдельности, а если поставить (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) в начало, то все работает, что здесь происходит ?

Comment: return всегда завершает функцию. По поводу условия - никогда не пиши подобную тернарщину: это просто ужасно. Напиши нормальные условия через if else или switch.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я учусь, поэтому пока делаю на всем, на тернарном, свиче и обычном if..else, чтобы лучше понимать. Про return не понял немного, оно же должно возвращать всегда значение в параметр функции, почему при вводе return'a внутри цикла выводится только первое значение, fizzbuzz, а пишем после цикла, так нормально возвращает тогда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Оператор `return` в вашем случае ничего не возвращает, а просто сразу выходит из функции. Вот по этому у вас выводится одно значение, а потом попадает на `return` и функция завершается.

   Например:

   ```
   function getFizzBuzz(num) {
   for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        //Выводим в консоль "fuzzbuzz" если условие выполняется
        (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) ? console.log("fizzbuzz") : ...;
        return; //выходим из функции
      }   
      return; //Если писать return тут, то мы дождемся сначала
      //завершение цикла, а потом сделаем выход из функции
   }
   ```

   В вашем случае, даже не требуется писать `return` после цикла т.к. функция и так завершится :)
2. Намного лучше переписать весь ваш громоздкий тернарный оператор в ветви `if`.

   Вот как выглядит тернарный оператор:

   ```
   условие ? если true : иначе false
   ```

   Получается когда вы пишите:

   ```
   (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) ? console.log("fizzbuzz") : ...;
   ```

   У вас если условие в круглых скобка выполняется, то выводится `fuzzbuzz`, иначе рассматривается то, что после `:`. Вот по этому нет смысла в конец добавлять такое же условие :)

Comment: С первым понятно, спасибо, со вторым щас распишу, а вы скажите где я не прав пожалуйста. Если мы например напишем сначало (i % 3 == 0) потом (i % 5 == 0) а потом уже (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0), то получается условие до последнего не дойдет ? Так как числа которые делятся на 3 и на 5 будут выводить fizz и buzz не давая выполнится условию fizzbuzz. А если вначале будет                              (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) то сначало функция проверит удовлетворяется ли условие это, если да, то вывели, если нет тогда выполняем то что далее.

Comment: @RayMistiko не совсем понял первую вашу идею, но вторая правильная. Если вы уж хотите через тернарный оператор сделать, то сначала проверяете, чтобы числа и на 3 И на 5 давало одинаковый остаток. Если это не так то отдельно проверяете на 3 и на 5.

Comment: @RayMistiko если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста выберите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :) Удачи